# How to associate user data between DynamoDB and Cognito

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync

thanks in advance for any help.  I've seen variations of this question, but mine offers a little twist.

I am working on an 'invite only' site (the twist), where administrators create the accounts for the users.  I have a form that has the necessary sign in information as well as other user data.  Here's where I'm getting tripped up:  Some user data goes to Cognito and some goes into DynamoDB but I can't seem to figure out how to associate the two.

To make my example easy (I hope), pretend that the admin form has First Name, Last Name, Email, and User Type.  Now first name, last name, and email belong in Cognito, but the UserType belongs on a User table in DynamoDB.  I can call Auth.sign_up and it creates the account in Cognito and sends the email to the new user and I can then separately write the user type to a user table in Dynamo DB but something needs to happen to let me know that the user in DynamoDB is the user in Cognito and I don't have all the necessary ids yet.

I've seen using triggers for this, and that could work if I didn't have other custom fields.  I could just set up a Post Sign Up trigger and use Lambda to write the new user from Cognito into DynamoDB with the basic name/email.  What about the other custom fields such as UserType.  It all needs to go through and be associated to the Cognito id in my DynamoDB table.  That way when the user logs in, I can pull this data entered in by the admin from DynamoDB.

FWIW, UserType is much more functional to the application and can be changed which is why I feel it belongs in DynamoDB.  It's not just "admin" or "normal user" -- it's more specific to the workflows I'm generating.

I may be overthinking this, but I can't work out what the workflow would be to make this work.

Thanks

Comment: This tutorial may be helpful, I’ve previously used it to do almost exactly what you’re doing where the admin created the users, with different user types (we stored the user types in the Cognito attributes): https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/building-fine-grained-authorization-using-amazon-cognito-user-pools-groups/

Comment: Hephalump, by saying "we stored the user types in the Cognito attributes" -- were you using a Lamda off of a trigger to populate that back into the DynamoDB?

Comment: We didn’t need to populate that data in Dynamo; Cognito is designed to handle authentication and authorization, so we leveraged the inbuilt capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for the responses... another follow up question.  What about person searches in your app, or lots of updates to these other attributes?  Our ‘user type’ isn’t exactly an authorization, more like app specific logic that gets changed and queried.